# Undefined index javascript php error

Tags: php, javascript, calendar

I am trying to create a function where my php calendar can be updated. This set of code is supposed to send $_POST["showmonth"] and $_POST["showyear"] to the controller but apparently it isn't working, causing the undefined index error. To be honest I am a total newbie in javascript and was just follow a tutorial on youtube. There are 2 similar functions for next and last month which are activated by the onClick trigger.Does anyone have any suggestion as to what the problem may be?

I am getting the error on line 9 and 10 of my php file,which where i announced

```
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth']; and $showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
```

Notice: Undefined index: showmonth in /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/html/calendar_start.php on line 9

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function intialCalendar(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth()+1; 
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST",url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
}
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/calcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" media = "all"/>
        <?php if (isset($title)): ?>
            <title>Calendar: <?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?></title>
        <?php else: ?>
            <title>Calendar</title>
        <?php endif ?>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
       <script src="js/calendar_functions.js"></script>




    </head>

    <body onload="initialCalendar();">



        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div id="top">
                <a href="calendar_start.php"><img alt="Calendar" src="img/square.png"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="middle">

             <div id="showCalendar"></div>
```

This is my php file

```
<?php

   // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 
     require("../templates/show_calendar.php");


$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$showmonth = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showmonth);
$showyear = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $showyear);

$day_count = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $showmonth,$showyear);
$pre_days = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6-(date(mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));

echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
echo '<div class="previous_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Previous Month" onclick="javascript:last_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="next_month"><input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Next Month" onclick="javascript:next_month();"></div>';
echo '<div class="title_bar">';
echo '<div class="showmonth">' . $showmonth . '/' . $showyear . '</div>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="week_days">';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Sun</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Mon</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Tue</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Wed</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Thur</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Fri</div>';
echo '<div class="days_of_week">Sat</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';

//previous month filler days
if($pre_days != 0)
{
    for($i=1; $i<=$pre_days; $i++)
    {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';
    }   
}

//current month
for($i=1; $i<=$day_count; $i++)
    {
        echo '<div class="cal_day">';
        echo '<div class="day_heading">'.$i.'</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    } 

//next month filler days
if($post_days != 0)
{
    for($i=1; $i<=$post_days; $i++)
    {
        echo '<div class="non_cal_day"></div>';

    }   
}
echo '</div>';

require("../templates/footer.php");



?>
```

Another source of error I suspect may be the use of require() to link my HTML with the controller(calendar_start.php), because it was the only difference between what I did and what the tutorial video taught. The video was using dreamweaver while i was using gedit  and without using require() I do not know how to link the php file to the html file.

Comment: Can you please tell us on which like exactly you are getting this error ?

Comment: Where are you getting undefined index error. It seems to be php error, right?

Comment: I am getting in my php file calendar_start.php where i announced
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];

Answer (score 0):

place

`hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request` 
right after  `hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Means

```
hr.open("POST",url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = return_data;
}
}
document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not seem to be working. May I know the rationale for doing so?

Comment: because it seems that you are sending data after you receive your response

Comment: I think that is because i'm activating it with <body onLoad="initialCalendar();">

Answer (score 0):

**Replce**

```
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
```

**With**

```
var showmonth = month;
var showyear = year;
```